# Unmutable field on python's dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have this dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class Couso:
    nome: str
    date: str = field(default=datetime.now(), init = False)
    id_: str = field(default=key())
```

Being key() a simple function that returns a str on len 32.

And when i create multiple classes of it (without specifing the id_ obviously) they all share the same id_

But why does it work this way? I cant understand.

Also, would this happen again with the attribute date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is called *before* `field` is called to create the field, so that every instance will have the same default `id_` attribute. It's the same as if you had written

```
x = key()


@dataclass
class Couso:
    ...
    id_ : str = field(default=x)
```

If you want to call `key` each time you create a new instance, use `default_factory` instead.

```
id_: str = field(default_factory=key)  # key is not called; it's passed as an object.
```

The same goes for `datetime.now`:

```
date: str = field(default_factory=datetime.now, init = False)
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot